# Handle specific route which is not using hash

Tags: angular

I have an URL :

www.example.be/#/

- I want to keep the hash
- I receive a redirection wrongPath/#/ which I want to redirect to /#/ but the router does not work because of the hash

I want to be able to evaluate the wrongpath to redirect it to another page when the param before is a hash.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the redirection in the server.

It depends on your backend, you should add a backend configuration that redirect all wrong paths to your target page.

Comment: With httpd is it possible ?

Comment: Yeah, any web server should provide this kind of feature, please refer to this [link](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ApacheRedirect.html) it describes how you could redirect in apache Web Server

Answer (score 0):

Add in `app.routing.module.ts`:

```
 { path: '**', redirectTo:"abc", pathMatch:"full" }
 window.location.href = "wrongPath2/#/"
```

Comment: I agree but I need just to delete the wrongPath and redirect to a correct page

Comment: Updated. WHy do you need to delete path, just route it.

Comment: Let's me give you an example : I have wrongPath1/#/ which one I want to redirect to component1 because I know that wrongPath1 is link to component1. I have wrongPath2/#/param1&param2 which one I want to redirect to component2 with all the params